# How does the 'not' keyword work in this code? I'm trying to understand if 'not' reverses the value of 'out_of_guesses'

Tags: python

```py
# Create a guessing game about your name, make the user have three tries only and end the game if the user cannot guess the answer in three tries.

answer = "jay"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

while guess.lower() != answer and not out_of_guesses:
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("What's my name? ")
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
    print("You lose. ")
else:
    print("You win. ")
```

I assigned a variable called `out_of_guesses` in this case; however, the while statement should use the `not` keyword and reverse the variable `out_of_guesses` to `True`. This isn't the case however because if the `not` keyword reversed the second condition to `True` then it would not exit the loop when `out_of_guesses` was `True`. Basically, what I'm asking is how does the `while` loop read the `not` statement? Am I misunderstanding something and how?

Comment: Not quite sure what your asking. The `not` reverse the value of `out_of_guesses`. [Your code seems to be working fine](https://tio.run/##bVBBDoIwELzvK9ZehJgQDTcj8eYLTIwn0mCRmrIltA3h9dgiBojuqTO7OzPbpreVpnQYOJlOtJghe/GewdMJYwKannmhHVlP7CesZC0DTkE7m@syH2kRdi5cGQEAXSWVwJFPlPbqUYybDCcnTg8kbXG9fgT0JUtcup5w4fmZCPXNKKlxNmK3itutwbpH4rU4I4vXk5PYLsPD2BA@5Sz2c8W1df4In@RfwKaV5C3v2qHSRiTBbNZbdDtJoen/Fwp4vQE).

Comment: That's what I'm confused about, if it reverses the value of ```out_of_guesses``` then shouldn't the while loop read the condition as ```out_of_guesses```being ```True```? So if it sets the condition of exiting the loop when it's ```True```, why does the loop stop when I set the value equal to ```True```?

Comment: The `not` operator does not modify the value of `out_of_guesses` whenever the condition is evaluated. Is that where your confusion is coming from?

Comment: "This isn't the case however because if the not keyword reversed the second condition to Truethen it would not exit the loop when out_of_guesses was True." In order for the loop to keep going, `out_of_guesses` has to be False **and** (hence the `and` in the code) `guess.lower()` has to be different from `answer`. If `guess.lower()` is equal to `answer`, then the loop can still exit even if `out_of_guesses` is False.

Comment: " if it reverses the value of out_of_guesses then shouldn't the while loop read the condition as out_of_guesses being True?" No; it doesn't **change** the value of `out_of_guesses`. The `while` loop "reads" (the word you actually want is "evaluates") **`not out_of_guesses`** as True. As a single, coherent unit. "why does the loop stop when I set the value equal to True" Because setting the value of `out_of_guesses` to True makes the value of `not out_of_guesses` equal to False.

Comment: Oh, is it the use of `and` or the use of `not` you are not understanding? When your code sets `out_of_guesses = True`, the `while` loop will still see: `... and not out_of_guesses:` which it sees as: `... and False:`

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to a smaller example that contains *only* the parts you don't understand? For example, do you get how `while not out_of_guesses:` would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you would better understand the logical expression if we inverted the sense of the boolean you have created:

```py
...
have_more_guesses = True

while guess.lower() != answer and have_more_guesses:
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("What's my name? ")
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        have_more_guesses = False

if have_more_guesses:
    print("You win. ")
else:
    print("You lose. ")
```

Note how I've inverted all the stages: the initialisation, the update and the final test.

This reads: "While you don't have the right answer, but you have more guesses keep guessing."

Comment: Thank you, I understood your answer and it works; but I still don't understand how the ```not out_of_guesses``` part works, I'm trying to understand if the ```not```keyword changes the value inside of the variable:

If the while loop registers each condition as true, does the ```not out_of_guesses``` command mean not (False) --> True? If this is the case the while command should have evaluated the second condition as ```True```. So it should mean that while ```out_of_guesses == True``` the loop would go on, but the loop ends with the variable being ```True```. I don't understand this.

Comment: The `not` operator inverts conditions, that is: `not False` is `True` and `not True` is `False`. It doesn't change variables. Only your assignments do that. Your code has: `out_of_guesses = True` when the users gets the answer wrong too many times. This means that in the `while` line, the expression `not out_of_guesses` now evaluates to `False` and terminates the loop.